# Keep losing sshfs connection on Linux Mint 19

Tags: ssh, mount, sshfs, linuxmint

**Edit:**
I set the dev up with a **brand new laptop with a fresh OS install**. Connection was still lost. Moved her to a different desk (which would be a different port on the switch in the closet), and the connection was lost. The dev that used to sit where she sits now never had this problem. Permissions are just like everyone else's on her directory.

I have a dev that keeps periodically losing connection. She is using PhpStorm for development and her files freeze, and the connection is lost.

On the remote server, this is in /var/log/auth.log at the time of disconnect:

```
Aug 15 12:28:06 dev_server sshd[24443]: Received disconnect from 192.168.27.230: 11: disconnected by user
Aug 15 12:28:06 dev_server sshd[24373]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user dev_username
```

Here is /home/dev_username/.ssh/config:

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.
# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.
# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
##   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
    TCPKeepAlive yes
    ServerAliveInterval 120
```

Here is /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Tried this for reconnect, but it did not work. It still crashes several times a day:

```
sshfs dev_username@dev_server:/home/www-data/dev_username /home/dev_username/dev_server -o IdentityFile=/home/dev_username/.ssh/id_rsa -o reconnect -o allow_other
```

I cannot wrap my head around this, and it is causing a good amount of frustration on her part (having to stop work, remounting the server, etc). I've tried tailing the logs throughout the day, but I'm not finding anything useful.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say conclusively what's going on, but there are a few things to check:

- Make sure the shell is clean on the remote server. The shell initialization scripts (`.bash_profile` etc.) should not produce any output. The affected user should check this with `ssh user@host true`, which should return no output. If it outputs anything, the command generating that output should be changed so that it no longer outputs anything.
- The ownership or permissions on the user's remote directory may be wrong. sshfs can fail if it encounters inaccessible files or directories on the remote server.
- Overly aggressive NAT devices in the network path may be dropping the session, causing both ends to be unable to communicate and eventually attempt to re-establish a connection. The developer has already set `ServerAliveInterval 120` to try to work around this, which should be fine, but if it's not enough, the NAT devices should get closer scrutiny. Especially if one is a home/SOHO router.

Comment: ssh user@host true asks for a passphrase.

Comment: Also, she is in the same room as all the other devs, who are connected to a switch. She is the only one experiencing this. The path is laptop (wired) --> switch in closet (same room) --> switch downstairs in server room.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce OK, well then enter the password, just as normal.

Comment: or if its allowed ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id host and the password is gone, but remind the security risk

Comment: Ok. I entered it and there was no output.

Comment: Then go to the next bullet point.

Comment: They are the same as every other developer. 2775 and owned by the user and group named "prog". 
I tried the mount on a completely different machine, and the same thing happened. No other dev is experiencing this.